# Is potential difference in electricity discovered by decrementing two average potentials?

Tags: potential

Is **potential difference** the difference (by mean of mathematical decrement; `Y-X`) by decremeting one measured average Joule of a charge (in point B in space) from another measured averaged Joule of a charge (in point A in space)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct that the potential is proportional to the potential energy a charged particle might have if it were hypothetically moved to some point in space. And that a potential difference is the difference between the potential at two points.

But practically we can't measure the (electrostatic potential) energy of a charge. In fact this energy has an arbitrary constant offset, depending what point we choose as the reference for zero potential.  Also remember that the potential can be defined at a point in space, even if there's no charge there to experience it

But potential difference has another definition, in terms of electric field,

$$V_{ab}=-\int_b^a \vec{E}\cdot d\vec\ell$$

and we can effectively measure potential difference according to this definition.

Comment: For someone like me, who never formally learned physics or electrical engineering, if we removed "measured" from my definition in the question, is the definition summarizingly correct?

Comment: @JohnDoea, yes, it's more or less correct, but the definition in terms of electric field is more useful most of the time. Remember that the potential can be defined at a point in space, even if there's no charge there to experience it.

Comment: Thank you so much; i think this should be inserted to the start of the answer by edit, before the formal definition (as I know comments sometime gets deleted).

Comment: Hello, again The Photon - please just one last thing: To better understand your answer I've asked the following separate question; please consider reading it and answer - thank you anyway; I greatly appreciate your very didactic help so far: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/500422/is-it-correct-to-say-that-electro-static-potential-of-a-charge-is-the-energy-of